# USB drive does not mount anymore - “Error unlocking...File exists”

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I just touched the plug of sn USB drive accidentally ... so, it was more or less removed without unmounting.

After trying to connect again, 2 of 3 partitions are working but one opens a dialogue box:

**“Error unlocking /dev/sdc3: Failed to activate device: File exists”**

It’s an encrypted volume.

It would be so great if anyone could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking for `/dev/mapper/`, searching for entries in `blkid` and looking at the data of `dmsetup info` I couldn't find anything that fit to the problem.

So, I just searched for running processes by `ps aux | grep <USERNAME>` and I was really surprised that there was still a process running in a subdirectory of the named partition.

I **killed the process** and now everything works fine again.
Maybe it helps anyone. And if it's just by finding out more about the commands here.

Comment: How do you find a running process that was using the old path by searching by username?

Comment: Just by checking the processes, @golimar. Of course, you can search for parts of the path, too.